# pandas remove rows with multiple criteria

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Consider the following pandas Data Frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'case_id': [1050, 1050, 1050, 1050, 1051, 1051, 1051, 1051],
    'elm_id': [101, 102, 101, 102, 101, 102, 101, 102],
    'cid': [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    'fx': [736.1, 16.5, 98.8, 158.5, 272.5, 750.0, 333.4, 104.2],
    'fy': [992.0, 261.3, 798.3, 452.0, 535.9, 838.8, 526.7, 119.4],
    'fz': [428.4, 611.0, 948.3, 523.9, 880.9, 340.3, 890.7, 422.1]})
```

When printed looks like this:

```
   case_id  cid  elm_id     fx     fy     fz
0     1050    1     101  736.1  992.0  428.4
1     1050    1     102   16.5  261.3  611.0
2     1050    2     101   98.8  798.3  948.3
3     1050    2     102  158.5  452.0  523.9
4     1051    1     101  272.5  535.9  880.9
5     1051    1     102  750.0  838.8  340.3
6     1051    2     101  333.4  526.7  890.7
7     1051    2     102  104.2  119.4  422.1
```

I need to remove rows where 'case_id' = values in a List and 'cid' = values in a List. For simplicity lets just use Lists with a single value: `cases = [1051]` and `ids = [1]` respectively. In this scenario I want the NEW Data Frame to have (6) rows of data. It should look like this because there were two rows matching my criteria which should be removed:

```
   case_id  cid  elm_id     fx     fy     fz
0     1050    1     101  736.1  992.0  428.4
1     1050    1     102   16.5  261.3  611.0
2     1050    2     101   98.8  798.3  948.3
3     1050    2     102  158.5  452.0  523.9
4     1051    2     101  333.4  526.7  890.7
5     1051    2     102  104.2  119.4  422.1
```

I've tried a few different things like:

`df2 = df[(df.case_id != subcase) & (df.cid != commit_id)]`

But this returns the inverse of what I was expecting:

```
2     1050    2     101   98.8  798.3  948.3
3     1050    2     102  158.5  452.0  523.9
```

I've also tried using `.query()`: `df.query('(case_id != 1051) & (cid != 1)')`
 but got the same (2) rows of results.

Any help and/or explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it is the logic problem:  you can replace the `&` (and) with `|` (or). 
`df[(df.case_id != 1051) | (df.cid != 1)]`    
`df.query('(case_id != 1051) | (cid != 1)') `

Comment: @Xinlu You are correct. This makes no sense to me, though. I want to meet both criteria (and) not either one of the criteria (or). Why does this work?

Comment: actually, you want to remove some observations: `(Not (A and B))`, which is equivalent to  `((Not A) or (Not B))`. Therefore, `df.query('not (case_id == 1051 & cid == 1)')` will give you the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks for the rows that meets the criteria, not drop it. You can drop thee rows using [.drop()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)
Use the following:

```
df.drop(df.loc[(df['case_id'].isin(cases)) & (df['cid'].isin(ids))].index)
```

Output:

```
     case_id    cid elm_id  fx  fy  fz
0   1050    1   101 736.1   992.0   428.4
1   1050    1   102 16.5    261.3   611.0
2   1050    2   101 98.8    798.3   948.3
3   1050    2   102 158.5   452.0   523.9
6   1051    2   101 333.4   526.7   890.7
7   1051    2   102 104.2   119.4   422.1
```

Comment: This is sooo close, but not there yet. To get it to work I needed to remove both instances of the (~) . We want to drop the values in the Lists. The (~) negates that. If you remove the (~) I will accept the answer as correct.